# Can't remove last prepended Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a to-do list. The tasks are objects that generate the necessary HTML code and prepend themselves to a `div` container. The string `listItemCode` contains all the necessary code for a list item, including code to create a `div` as a remove button in every item.

As you can see in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robocopatrick/kqw65kpw/5/) everything works, only the top-most item in the list (the one saying "Relax") won't remove itself when its remove button is clicked.

If you add a new list item via the inputs and the submit button the last IT becomes unremovable but the second-top-most item becomes removable.

I am pulling my hair out trying to find the bug.

```
// Object Array in which to store all the items
var tasks = [];

// Make list sortable
$("#mainlist").sortable();

// Task Constructor
var Task = function (title, description) {
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    var listItemCode = "<div class='listItem'>" + "<input class='title' name='title' onClick='this.select();' placeholder='Title' value='" + title + "'><br>" + "<input class='description' name='description' onClick='this.select();' placeholder='Description' value='" + description + "'>" + "<div class='date'>" + date() + "</div>" + "<div class='removeButton'>X</div>" + "</div>";

    $(".removeButton").click(function() {
        listItemCode = "";
        $(this).parent(".listItem").fadeTo(200, 0).slideUp('fast', function() { $(this).remove(); }); 
    });

    // Push to Object Array containing all tasks
    tasks.push(this);
    // Display in Browser
    $("#mainlist").prepend(listItemCode);
};

// Add Dummy Tasks for Designing
addDummyTasks(true);

// New Task added by User
$("input[name=submit]").click(function () {
    var newTask = new Task($("input[name=title]").val(),
                           $("input[name=description]").val());
});

// Get, formats and returns the current date
function date() {
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    var hour = today.getHours();
    var minute = today.getMinutes();
    //var date = "Created on " + dd + "." + mm + "." + yyyy + " at " + hour + ":" + minute;
    var currentDateTime = dd + "." + mm + "." + yyyy + " at " + hour + ":" + minute;
    return currentDateTime;
}

// Dummy Tasks for Designing
function addDummyTasks(x) {
    if (x === true) {
        var task1 = new Task("Milk the cow", "You know she wants it.");
        var task2 = new Task("Get funky", "Boogie on down to the club.");
        var task3 = new Task("Freakify", "Get your freak on.");
        var task4 = new Task("Relax", "Time to get jiggy with it.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a delegated event handler instead:

```
$(document).on('click', ".removeButton", function() {
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/kqw65kpw/8/

This way it checks the selector at *event time*, so it does not matter when the item was added.

You only need to register this once, so moved it outside your function.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the lighting fast answer, TrueBlueAussie! This seems to be the most elegant solution. I will go with this. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you create a new Task `var listItemCode` does not exists in the DOM yet. Thus, `$('.removeButton').click()` is not running because no element exists. The fist created task gets its event when the second task is created, and the second task when the third is created and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I commented out the `$(".removeButton").click(function() { ... });` function and moved it into an `onclick` attribute when playing with your JSFiddle and was able to get it to work. Though not my favorite way of implementing click handlers, this will make sure it's attached to every existing DOM element it's applied to within your list.

Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqw65kpw/13/) for your code.

```
var Task = function (title, description) {
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    var listItemCode = "<div class='listItem'>" 
                       + "<input class='title' name='title' onClick='this.select();' placeholder='Title' value='" + title + "'><br>" 
                       + "<input class='description' name='description' onClick='this.select();' placeholder='Description' value='" + description + "'>" 
                     + "<div class='date'>" + date() + "</div>"

                     // Here's where I added the onClick handler it.
                     + "<div class='removeButton' onClick='$(this).parent(\".listItem\").fadeTo(200, 0).slideUp(\"fast\");' >X</div>" 
                     + "</div>";

    //$(".removeButton").click(function() {
    //  listItemCode = "";
    //    $(this).parent(".listItem").fadeTo(200, 0).slideUp('fast', function() { $(this).remove(); }); 
    //});

    // Push to Object Array containing all tasks
    tasks.push(this);
    // Display in Browser
    $("#mainlist").prepend(listItemCode);
};
```

Comment: It is best to *not* mix inline event handlers with jQuery handlers. It separates the registration code from the handler code for no reason and defeats some of the extra benefits of using jQuery event handlers. Any mention of dynamic elements would immediately indicate a delegated event handler was required.